"Floating point exception" with gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT and GDAL 4.3.1
My application uses GDAL 3.4.1 and proj 8.2.1 with the Python bindings and I'm using gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT to reproject a Geodetic (epsg:4326) to Mercator (epsg:3857) dataset.
Sometimes, but not always, I will get a "Floating point exception" in the  and the application will crash in the warp kernel.  I've turned on CPL_DEBUG=ON and I see an output like this

GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKRealCase() Src=0,545,641x113 Dst=0,640,512x128
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKRealCase() Src=636,545,565x113 Dst=512,640,451x128
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKRealCase() Src=0,655,641x113 Dst=0,768,512x128
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKRealCase() Src=636,655,565x113 Dst=512,768,451x128
GDAL: GDALWarpKernel()::GWKRealCase() Src=0,765,641x113 Dst=0,896,512x128
Floating point exception

I've made a simple sample application that reproduces the issue:
from osgeo import gdal, osr
import argparse

def renderTile(filename):
    # Open the dataset
    src_ds = gdal.Open(filename)

    # Warp the dataset to mercator using a WarpedVRT
    dst_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    dst_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3857)
    dst_wkt = dst_srs.ExportToWkt()

    error_threshold = 0.125
    resampling = gdal.GRA_Bilinear
    warped_dataset = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(
                src_ds,                
                None,
                dst_wkt,
                resampling,
                error_threshold
            )

    # Read the first band from the warped dataset
    band = warped_dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
    data = band.ReadAsArray()
    print("Read data from %s length=%s" % (filename, len(data)))

    # Close the dataset
    band = None
    warped_dataset = None
    src_ds = None

def main():
    args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args.add_argument("filename", help="filename to render")
    args = args.parse_args()
    filename = args.filename

    for i in range(0, 100):
        print("Starting attempt %s" % i)
        renderTile(filename)
        print("finished %s" % i)
    print("done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I've been able to reproduce this with multiple files, but the one I've been testing the most has a gdalinfo like this:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: mt_rainier_90m.tif
Size is 1201, 1201
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-122.000416666666666,47.000416666666666)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333333333,-0.000833333333333)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-122.0004167,  47.0004167) (122d 0' 1.50"W, 47d 0' 1.50"N)
Lower Left  (-122.0004167,  45.9995833) (122d 0' 1.50"W, 45d59'58.50"N)
Upper Right (-120.9995833,  47.0004167) (120d59'58.50"W, 47d 0' 1.50"N)
Lower Right (-120.9995833,  45.9995833) (120d59'58.50"W, 45d59'58.50"N)
Center      (-121.5000000,  46.5000000) (121d30' 0.00"W, 46d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768

I've ran it through GDB and I get this stack trace where the app crashes
rogram received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
__atan_fma (x=1.0486944322247436) at ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_atan.c:116
116     ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_atan.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __atan_fma (x=1.0486944322247436) at ../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_atan.c:116
#1  0x00007ffff42b912d in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22
#2  0x00007ffff4301a8f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22
#3  0x00007ffff430db08 in proj_trans () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22
#4  0x00007ffff4311311 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22
#5  0x00007ffff4301918 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22
#6  0x00007ffff430db08 in proj_trans () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.22
#7  0x00007ffff6338c72 in OGRProjCT::TransformWithErrorCodes (this=this@entry=0x55555612d8a0, nCount=nCount@entry=84, x=<optimized out>, y=<optimized out>, z=<optimized out>, t=0x0, panErrorCodes=0x55555637c230) 
    at ogrct.cpp:2465
#8  0x00007ffff633b788 in OGRProjCT::TransformWithErrorCodes (panErrorCodes=<optimized out>, t=<optimized out>, z=<optimized out>, y=<optimized out>, x=<optimized out>, nCount=<optimized out>,
    this=0x55555612d8a0) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:363
#9  OGRProjCT::Transform (this=0x55555612d8a0, nCount=84, x=<optimized out>, y=<optimized out>, z=<optimized out>, t=<optimized out>, pabSuccess=0x55555645b990) at ogrct.cpp:2038
#10 0x00007ffff63eb473 in GDALReprojectionTransform (pTransformArg=0x55555611a0a0, bDstToSrc=1, nPointCount=84, padfX=0x55555663b830, padfY=0x55555663bad0, padfZ=0x55555663bd70, panSuccess=0x55555645b990)        
    at gdaltransformer.cpp:3180
#11 0x00007ffff63e8a7f in GDALGenImgProjTransform (pTransformArgIn=0x555555d9fb50, bDstToSrc=1, nPointCount=84, padfX=0x55555663b830, padfY=0x55555663bad0, padfZ=<optimized out>, panSuccess=0x55555645b990)       
    at gdaltransformer.cpp:2529
#12 0x00007ffff63e99f9 in GDALApproxTransform (pCBData=0x55555611d800, bDstToSrc=<optimized out>, nPoints=84, x=0x55555663b830, y=0x55555663bad0, z=0x55555663bd70, panSuccess=0x55555645b990)
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
   p:3883
#13 0x00007ffff640db95 in GDALWarpOperation::ComputeSourceWindow (this=this@entry=0x55555618e6b0, nDstXOff=nDstXOff@entry=0, nDstYOff=nDstYOff@entry=896, nDstXSize=nDstXSize@entry=512, 
    nDstYSize=nDstYSize@entry=128, pnSrcXOff=pnSrcXOff@entry=0x7fffffffcd78, pnSrcYOff=0x7fffffffcd80, pnSrcXSize=0x7fffffffcd88, pnSrcYSize=0x7fffffffcd90, pdfSrcXExtraSize=0x7fffffffcbe8, 
    pdfSrcYExtraSize=0x7fffffffcbe0, pdfSrcFillRatio=0x0) at gdalwarpoperation.cpp:2754
#14 0x00007ffff640f644 in GDALWarpOperation::WarpRegionToBuffer (this=0x55555618e6b0, nDstXOff=0, nDstYOff=896, nDstXSize=512, nDstYSize=128, pDataBuf=0x555556a24fb0, eBufDataType=GDT_Int16, 
    nSrcXOff=<optimized out>, nSrcYOff=<optimized out>, nSrcXSize=<optimized out>, nSrcYSize=<optimized out>, dfSrcXExtraSize=<optimized out>, dfSrcYExtraSize=<optimized out>, dfProgressBase=0

I've tried this using GDAL 3.8.4 and Proj 9.3.1 and it happens much less often but it still fails with a Floating Point Exception sometimes.
Does anyone see something I'm obviously doing wrong and have some tips?

Thanks for that, I've corrected the GDAL version and included the proj version along with a gdb stack trace.

I can't reproduce in Ubuntu 22.04 with GDAL 3.4.1 + proj 8.2.1 from repos or GDAL 3.8.5 + proj 9.4.0 in a conda env (conda-forge). Suggest you raise a GDAL or Proj issue.
